# Is there WebGL support in Flutter WebView?

Tags: flutter

**EDIT 5/28/2020: Not sure when exactly this was fixed, but as of Flutter 1.17.0, I no longer have this problem.**

I've been trying to implement an iframe in Flutter WebView that requires WebGL (it displays a 3d model).

However, I get a warning saying WebGL in my browser is supported but not enabled. Here's a snippet for getting to `https://get.webgl.org`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class ModelView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Model View'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://get.webgl.org',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Which displays:

[image: Flutter WebView WebGL]

Is there a way to enable WebGL for `WebView`? Or is it impossible right now?

Comment: does this page work in standalone chrome?

Comment: Yes. Standalone Chrome shows a rotating box and says my browser supports WebGL.

Comment: Are you getting better results now? Is WebGL in Flutter a feasible option?

Comment: @AdrianMoisa Yes, I've been using it without problems since.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`webview_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) on Android uses [Platform Views](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-views) to embed [Android WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) while [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) is used on iOS. Both have WebGL support so displaying https://get.webgl.org/ should work fine.